# Specific songs for sporting events

Tags: trivia, international-sports

FIFA World Cup Songs date back to the 1980s, with for example:

- In 2010 [Waka Waka (This Time for Africa)](https://youtu.be/pRpeEdMmmQ0) by Shakira was the 2010 Official FIFA World Cup song.
- In 2014 [We Are One (Ole Ola)](https://youtu.be/TGtWWb9emYI) by Pitbull was the 2014 Official FIFA World Cup song.
- Now, 2018 [Live It Up](https://youtu.be/kFMZUxX6K6o) by Nicky Jam is the 2018 Official FIFA World Cup song.

**MY QUESTION**:

Is there any other major sporting events, on the **International Level**, that dedicates a different song to their event each iteration, as the FIFA World Cup has a different song as their *official FIFA World Cup song* each year?

If so, detail what the sporting event is, the title of the song, and the song's year/season of significance.

Comment: You probably want to narrow down `National or International Level` to a smaller and explicit list of competition. Otherwise the question is likely going to get marked as too broad!